# Python date formatting

Tags: python, date

How would I get a function to take the date in terms of YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD and DD.MM.YYYY and return YYYY-MM-DD? 
I’ve tried a few ways which would work for one of the formats but then not the other

Comment: try to parse all 3 formats using datetime and catch the exceptions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the formats are trivially detectable by their delimiter though.

Comment: @MitchWheat: I fail to see how that dupe applies here. There is zero parsing going on in that question or any of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to try all with one line, So you can try like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = "30-4-1994"
for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d', '%d.%m.%Y'):
    try:
        example_time =  datetime.strptime(dt, fmt).date()
        print(example_time)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

O/P will be in YYYY-MM-DD format like this :

```
1994-04-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Just switch on the delimiter string in your input to pick a suitable `datetime.strptime()` format:

```
from datetime import datetime

FORMATS = {'-': '%Y-%m-%d', '/': '%Y/%m/%d', '.': '%d.%m.%Y'}
def convertdate(ds, outputformat='%Y-%m-%d', _formats=FORMATS):
    for delim, format in _formats.items():
        if delim in ds:
            return datetime.strptime(ds, format).strftime(outputformat)
```

Demo:

```
>>> convertdate('2012-03-12')
'2012-03-12'
>>> convertdate('2012/03/12')
'2012-03-12'
>>> convertdate('12.03.2012')
'2012-03-12'
```